# Calling a method from a different form

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms. First one (Form1) has a datagrid, the second one (Form2) has a button to call a function in Form1 to refresh the datagrid.

All i want to achieve is; on clicking the button in form2 , form1 datagrid should refresh (this refresh will be as a result of calling the function temp_proj )
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Form2 should have an event that Form1 subscribes to and refreshes the datagrid when the event is called.

Comment: You have options, first , if you need refresh datagridview when button form is closed, you can use showDialog,. If you need refresh que button as pressed  and not need close form, you can add a event on button form, fire the event when button as presed and add handle on datagridview form for refresh, probably you need call invoke

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class where you store the instance of your form1.

You can call your form1 update method like

Globals.Form1.UpdateUI() from another class. You can either instantiate in your class or store it as a variable in global class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the delegates and events concepts. Consider the following code segments:

**Code in Form1**(the one which having the grid)

```
delegate void RefreshGrid();

// Method or event that opens form 2
public void OpenNextForm()
{
    RefreshGrid EventRefresh = new RefreshGrid(RefreshGridEvent);
    Form2 frm2Instance = new Form2();
    frm2Instance.parentEvent = EventRefresh;
    frm2Instance.Show();
}
```

**Code in Form2**

```
public Delegate parentEvent;
public void Form2ButtonClick()
{
     parentEvent.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Please note the following:

- Form2ButtonClick: will be the button click event from the Form2
- OpenNextForm : will be the event in Form1 that opens the Form2